# Trying to find Taylor expansion of $\arcsin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1^2\times3^2\times...\times(2n-1)^2}{2^{2n}(2n+1)!}=?$

So my guess is this is some kind of $\arcsin(x)$.

My attempt:

Let $f(x) = \arcsin(x)$ then

$f'(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

We know that : $(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^n$.So then with $\alpha=-\frac 12$ and $x\leftarrow-x^2$ we get that:

$$\frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-\frac12)(-\frac 32)(-\frac 52)...(-\frac {2n-1}2)}{n!}(-1)^nx^{2n}=1+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1\times3\times5\times...\times(2n-1)}{2^nn!}x^{2n}.$$

if we integrate both sides we get that:

$$f(x)=x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1\times3\times...\times(2n-1)}{2^nn!(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$$

Is there something wrong with my expansion? I think I might've made a mistake somewhere

Comment: The title of the question is a bit misleading.

Comment: It's correct. The first term, conventionally, corresponds to $n=0$ in the general formula. There is a more compact form: $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n-1)!!^2}{4^n(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{16^n (2n+1)}=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}-1\right)\,dx=2\arcsin\frac{1}{2}-1=\frac{\pi}{3}-1. $$

Comment: Can you be more explicit at firs step?

Comment: @C.Cristi: $$\frac{(2n-1)!!^2}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{\left[(2n)!/(2^n n!)\right]^2}{4^n(2n+1)!}=\frac{(2n)!\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n (2n+1)!}=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n(2n+1)}.$$